# Tensorflow - Get amount of samples in Queue?

Tags: python, tensorflow

For performance monitoring I would like to keep an eye on the currently queued example. I am balancing the amount of threads I'm using for filling the queue and the optimal maximum size of the queue.
How do I obtain this information? I am using a `tf.train.batch()`, but I guess the information might be somewhere down in the `FIFOQueue`?
I would have expected this to be a local variable but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tldr: if your queue is created by `tf.batch`, you can get size with `sess.run("batch/fifo_queue_Size:0")`

A `FIFOQueue` object provides a `size()` method which creates an op that gives number of elements on queue. However, if you are using `tf.batch`, FIFOQueue is created inside the method and this object is not exposed externally.

In particular you see this in [input.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5a5a25ea3ebef623e07fb9a46419a9df377a37a5/tensorflow/python/training/input.py#L648)

```
queue = _which_queue(dynamic_pad)(
    capacity=capacity, dtypes=types, shapes=shapes, shared_name=shared_name)
print("Enqueueing: ", enqueue_many, tensor_list, shapes)
_enqueue(queue, tensor_list, num_threads, enqueue_many)
summary.scalar("queue/%s/fraction_of_%d_full" % (queue.name, capacity),
               math_ops.cast(queue.size(), dtypes.float32) *
               (1. / capacity))
```

Since `queue` is local, you can't get a hold of its `size()` method. However since the `size()` has been called in order to construct the summary, the appropriate `size` op is in the graph and you can call it by name. You can find the name of the node by doing something like this

```
x = tf.constant(1)
q = tf.train.batch([x], 2)
tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
```

You will see

```
node {
  name: "batch/fifo_queue_Size"
  op: "QueueSize"
  input: "batch/fifo_queue"
  attr {
    key: "_class"
    value {
      list {
```

From this you can tell that `batch/fifo_queue_Size` is the name of the op, and hence `batch/fifo_queue_Size:0` is the name of the first output, so you can get the size by doing something like this:

```
sess.run("batch/fifo_queue_Size:0")
```

If you have multiple `batch` ops, the names will be automatically deduped into `batch_1/fifo_queue_Size`, `batch_2/fifo_queue_Size`, etc

Alternatively you can call your node with `tf.batch(...name="mybatch")` and then the name of tensor will be `mybatch/fifo_queue_Size:0`

Comment: Excellent write-up. Also totally missed the scalar summary inside batch - it's because i don't do a `merge_all_summaries` but get them from my own scopes. Thanks for your time Yaroslav.