# TensorFlow: Does queuing examples in parallel speed up a batch creation if tf.train.batch is already dequeuing examples in parallel?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning

In the TensorFlow-slim documentation, there is a ParallelReader object that can read TFRecords data in parallel through having multiple readers to take in example strings into queue. However, if I am not mistaken tf.train.batch dequeues examples from a queue and is able to do so in parallel with the argument `num_threads`. If that is the case, is it necessary that both the batch creation and reading of data must have the same speed otherwise one will cause a slower creation of a batch?

I am actually not very sure whether the dequeue operation happens in tf.train.batch or when a queue_runner is manually created to dequeue the examples since I believe tf.train.batch can effectively replace the queue_runner operation. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as your first paragraph goes: the answer is that each step in your input pipeline should have enough bandwidth to feed the model (and probably not too much more). You can easily run into bottlenecks if e.g. moving from one queue to another is fast but not enough data is being fed to the first queue (because of I/O issues, for example). You could also imagine having huge numbers of parallel readers and plenty of I/O bandwidth but only a single thread responsible for collecting all of those examples being the bottleneck. Some back-of-the-envelope computation may help, but ultimately you should be [monitoring the number of examples in each queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40191367/tensorflow-get-amount-of-samples-in-queue).

As for the second question, [tf.train.batch does start its own queue runner](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops/input_pipeline#batch). The actual enqueuing/dequeuing happens asynchronously, which is why it's important to monitor queue sizes to make sure that training isn't consuming data faster than the input pipeline is producing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I am training using a supervisor, I realised there is a summary called batch/queue/batch/fifo_queue/fraction_of_8_full` tracked in TensorBoard. Is this the correct metric to monitor? In particular, should I monitor whether this metric is consistently full in the queue, and is it correct that if my queue is consistenly below full, I should increase the `num_threads` argument in `tf.train.batch`? Currently, I am seeing a queue that is occasionally full and occasionally nearly empty (I take compute summaries every 10 steps). What is recommended in this instance?

Comment: Also, generally speaking, should the number of threads in `tf.train.batch` be equal to the number of parallel readers? Is there a trade off in having as many readers and `num_threads` as possible?

Comment: You may just want to increase the queue capacity if it's sometimes full and sometimes empty (assuming that memory is available to do so). More threads in the input pipeline probably don't have too much overhead, but you're very quickly going to be limited by whichever physical device you're reading from. If so, you might consider dividing the dataset between multiple machines.